# Fragment layouts overlapping on popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Fragment A

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        TextView tvTest = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        tvTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB()).addToBackStack("tag").commit();            }
        });
        return rootView;
```

Fragment B

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    TextView tvTest = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    tvTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentC()).commit();            }


    });
    return rootView;
```

Fragment C

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
TextView tvTest = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
tvTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
});
return rootView;
}
```

On clicking on tvTest in **Fragment C**,I see that layout of Fragment A and Fragment C **overlapping** each other

**Expectecd Behaviour-**
While replacing Fragment C with Fragment B,Fragment B is destroyed since its a replace transaction without addToBackStack().Now when using popBackStack() in Fragment C ,Fragment C should be destroyed and Fragment A  should be clearly visible.

Comment: try using add() instead of replace() in fragment A while opening fragment B. See what's happening

Comment: @PrashanthVerma with that fragment A and B layouts overlapping and nothing happens on using popBackStack() in Fragment C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how `FragmentManager` backstack works. It is a stack of `FragmentTransaction` **not** `Fragment`.

Your code has the following transactions.

- A -> B (Transaction added to back stack)
- B -> C

C then pops the back stack (it reverses the last transaction in the stack (A -> B)) - which becomes B -> A. This results in both A and C visible.

Comment: okay..but when i did B->C ,fragment B should have destroyed at that time since i used replace without addToBackStack..So when C pops the back stack fragment B was already destroyed and fragment A should only be there in backstack?

Comment: Does that mean that replace call in B->C would not destroy fragment B instance since backstack is keeping reference to it?

Comment: I cannot say with certainty as to the implementation of fragment manager. But yes I would imagine fragment b instance is kept for the reasons you describe, and merely it's view is destroyed.